# Ruby on rails How can i calculate the distance between 2 positions GPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is some Gem which can calculate the distance between 2 GPS position?

Comment: you can use geocoder gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done using Geocoder. Add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'geocoder'
```

and then run

```
bundle install
```

I assume that you want to display the nearest stores if you have the location of the user. Geocoder has a `near` method which does exactly that.

In your store model(`app/models/store.rb`), add

```
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode
```

Note that the address of the store to be used by the geocoder gem.
The second line will auto-populate the latitude and longitude fields once a new record is created.

Now, in your controller, add the code to fetch the nearby stores for a given user(if the user's location is known).

```
def index
@current_lat = params[:lat]
@current_lon = params[:lon]
if (@current_lat.nil? || @current_lon.nil?)
  @stores = Store.all
  render json: @stores
else
 @stores = Store.near([@current_lat, @current_lon], 10, :units => :km)
end
```

end

This fetches the stores which are within 10 km from the user's current location. You can also pass in a units hash which defauls to miles.

For more, 
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#for-activerecord-models

Comment: @Alain Professional The geocoder gem uses the address of the store to auto-populate the latitude and longitude fields in your store record. Now, you can call `near` method on Store and pass it the user's latitude and longitude from which we want to calculate the distance.

Comment: @AlainProfessional By default, this query returns the store objects ordered by distance. Read https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#for-activerecord-models